# select field in a pivot table laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables describing books, person and person_book. These look like this:

```
 book -> id, name
 author -> id, name
 book_person -> book_id, person_id, status  (pivot table)
```

the relation is ok  and this are my tables

```
books         person       book_person
1 | book1     1|Peter    id | book_id| person_id|status
2 | book2     2|Ren       1 |    1   |    1     |  1
3 | book3                 2 |    1   |    2     |  0
                          3 |    2   |    2     |  1
                          4 |    3   |    2     |  1
```

whit laravel orm, how i can get only the person '2'(ren) where status = 1

im doing this on my Controller

```
 $bp  = Book::find(2);
```

and my view

```
@foreach($bp->person as $p)
   $p->pivot->id 
   $p->pivot->status 
@endforeach
and this bring me 
book_person (2,3,4) but i cant select only the status 1
```

where i can to do the 'where' query if the book_person doesnt have a model?

Comment: do you have Person model and any relation  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those relations are many to many, you can use `wherePivot`to filter based on data stored pivot table.

```
$bp  = Book::find(2);
$persons = $book->persons()->wherePivot('status', 1)->get();
```

You can also eager load it. And continue using you view.

```
$bp = Book::with(['persons' => function ($q) {
    $q->wherePivot('status', 1);
}])->find(2);
```

Comment: Is `$bp` means `$book` ? Here `$bp  = Book::find(2);`

Answer (score 0):

As you did not mention about model relation . Use laravel DB query by joining  table

```
$result = DB::table("person as p")
->join("book_person as bp","bp.person_id","=","p.id")
->join("book as b","bp.book_id","=","b.id")//if you want book detail also
->where('p.id','2')
->where('bp.status',1)
->get();
```